# How can I change the output of Ultralytics Yolov8 model.predict() in PyCharm terminal?

Tags: pycharm, yolo

How to change Ultralytics Yolov8 model.predict() output in pycharm terminal? When you enter the code, the following is displayed in the terminal: 0: 384x640 (no detection), 8.0 ms How to change it and add at what point in time it happened.

```
                                                               .
```

Comment: Is there something typed in the prompt, I can't see anything.

Comment: no, there's nothing there